The curve $|z+1|-|z-1|=\Re(z)$ in Argand plane
Suppose $z=x+iy$. Given that $$|z+1|-|z-1|=\Re(z)$$
Squaring this we have
$$|z+1|^2+|z-1|^2-2|z^2-1|=x^2$$
$$\implies 2|z|^2+2-x^2=2|z^2-1|$$
squaring this will make it 4th degree polynomial in $x,y$ and give a non-standard curve. Can someone help me in finding with proof what conic it may be?

Is $x$ the real part of $z$?

Yes, please $z=x+iy$.

The curve isn't a conic, it is an ellipse together with line $x = 0$. Try squaring both sides of $|z+1| = x + |z-1|$, get rid of common factor $x$ to get the ellipse.

$$|z+1|-|z-1|=\Re(z)=x$$
Take $z=x+iy$ then the given equation is
$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}=x$$
which can be put in a more interesting and simple form
by denoting LHS as $$\sqrt{P}-\sqrt{Q}=x \cdots (1).$$ then
we get $$P-Q=4x \cdots (2)$$ and
$$\sqrt{P}+\sqrt{Q}=4 \cdots (3)$$
Adding (1) and (3), we get
$$2\sqrt{P}=4+x \implies 4(x+1)^2+4y^2=(4+x)^2.$$
Which up on simplification gives the standard ellipse:
$$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{3}=1.$$
Edit: Yes, as mentioned @archille hui $x=0$ will also be an additional locus as $|iy+1|-|iy-1|=x=0$.

Yes, thank you.
